# Is there some way to resolve C struct dynamically in Go?

Tags: go, struct

I defined a struct in C like:

```
struct SomeStruct
{
    int var1;
    bool var2;
    double var3;
    int var4[10];
    int var5[10][10];
}
struct SomeStruct entity;
```

And somewhere there was a input box that some user input in GO:

```
func("entity.var3")
```

It will return value of entity.var3 in C struct.

Actually I could already implement it in python by cffi and:

```
def get_one_variable(buffer, setup):
    value = buffer
    for level in setup:
        if isinstance(level, str):
            value = getattr(value, level)
        else:
            [base, extends] = level
            value = getattr(value, base)
            for extend in extends:
                value = value[extend]
    return value
```

Where buffer is python cffi data pointer defined with "FFI.cdef" and setup resolved by:

```
def parse_variable(self, line):
    line = line.replace('\n', '').replace(' ', '')
    split = line.split('.')
    variable = []
    for child in split:
        match = self.BASE_EXT_REGEX.match(child)
        if match is None:
            variable.append(child)
        else:
            base_name = match.group('base_name')
            ext_name = match.group('ext_name')
            variable.append([base_name, [int(index) for index in
                                         ext_name.replace('[', ']').replace(']]', ']').strip(']').split(']')]])
    return variable
```

So I can dynamically resolve "entity.var1", "entity.var2", "entity.var3", "entity.var4[0]", "entity.var5[0][1]".

Is there something or someway similar in GO?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Are you using C code in Go (i.e. `cgo`)? Or are you just trying to get the same functionality in Go that you have observed in C and Python?

Comment: Go is a statically typed language, use CGO to call c code in Go : https://golang.org/cmd/cgo/

Comment: I mean python's cffi library could load C struct into memory and organize it like a "tree" of classes which make it possible to resolve a variable name string like "entity.var1" by looking into that tree and find the desired leaf and output its value. Is there anything similar in GO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is handled by CGO which is a special package in Go that allows for easy C integration. You can read more about it [here](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/cgo) and [here](https://godoc.org/cmd/cgo). Given your examples, a simple CGO example would be:

```
/*
struct SomeStruct
{
    int var1;
    bool var2;
    double var3;
    int var4[10];
    int var5[10][10];
}
*/
import "C"
import "fmt"

func main(){
    thing := C.struct_SomeStruct{}
    thing.var1 = C.int(5)
    fmt.Printf("My Struct's var field %d\n",int(thing.var1))
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But could GO dynamically resolve C struct? The program does not know desired variable name before it runs. 
fmt.Printf("My Struct's var field %d\n", something read from input stream)

Comment: Just like python's cffi, which can generate a "tree" of struct in memory and make it possible to resolve variable dynamically.

Comment: CGO can be used to link against libraries (dll,so,a,etc), just make sure the header file is in the CGO pre-amble and the library is in the compilers search paths. Now this is a compile time solution, though dynamic in that you change a shared library, but you do not need to change the go code. As far as the ultra dynamic solution that Python offers, Go actually can do this with other Go code using `plugins`, but cannot do it with C code. Basically as long as you are not taking the shared library as an argument, you should be able to do everything you need with CGO.